# how to clean unwanted data in a column in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column name Newspath varchar(max). The data in the column is like this

Newspath
423.jpg64265
789.jpg41546
546.jpg7894

I want to remove all the words after .jpg word like this

Newspath
423.jpg
789.jpg
546.jpg

Please help

Comment: some one has added unwanted to all the rows in the specified column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you need to update all the rows of your table. You can update all the rows of your table like

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE  yourtable 
SET newpath = SUBSTR(newpath,0,CHARINDEX('jpg',newpath)+2)
```

You can look at more for [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and [Charindex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx).

Comment: Thanks buddy i appreciate your help... let me check its working or not

Comment: This should indeed work fine. Lolled at your name @Coder of Code

Comment: The charindex function requires 2 to 3 arguments.

Comment: Check the update  in a hurry missed the second argument. Sorry for that.

Comment: i need a complete error free query for the above problem... i have edited my question for ease

Comment: No need to use BEGIN TRAN unless you are running more than one update/insert/delete. SQL Server implicitly wrap these commands in a transaction.